# how to find number of days by subtracting previous date from current date

Tags: php

Is it possible to find the no of days between two date fields.

i want to remove the user if user does not login within 30 days. 
on every login `login_date` field will update.

i want to subtract two fields `login_date` and `current_date` 
and if answer is 30 or greater than 30 it will delete that user.

i am new in php and need help..
i am working on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try this function will get number of days between two dates.

```
function dateDiff($start, $end) {

  $start_ts = strtotime($start);

  $end_ts = strtotime($end);

  $difference = $end_ts - $start_ts;

  return round($difference / 86400);

 }
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use DateTime and DateInterval objects.

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2007-03-24");
$date2 = new DateTime("2009-06-26");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "days difference ".$interval->d." days ";
```

read more php [DateTime::diff manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 2):

If you use timestamp format - you can use condition:

```
$month = 30*86400; 
if ($current_date - $login_date > $month){
    delete_user();
}
```

If you use datetime format - you can transform this format to timestamp with function strtotime

Answer (score 1):

Following will return exact days between two dates.

> ```
> $last_login_date = "2012-04-01";
> $current_date = "2012-04-30";
>
> echo "Days: ".round(abs(strtotime($current_date)-strtotime($last_login_date))/86400);
> ```

Hope this helps.